# Can a Docker container be started directly from Bluemix Workload Scheduler?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

I want to schedule some batch jobs from Bluemix workload scheduler using a (Docker) container.

Container is dedicated to a batch job. Batch job is the command for the container.

I do not see a way to start a container from the scheduler directly. How can this be achieved? The solutions I see

1. By running remote command. This may need a VM and can fail of a single point.
2. By invoking Docker as REST services. This takes care of HA, but "cf ic" options like group creation will not be available.

Is there any other solution which I have overlooked?

Comment: Have you seen the ibm_wa_agent container? This is a pre-built docker container that contains a workload scheduler agent and allow to run jobs within Bluemix from workload scheduler.